Error: No Module Named 'example' When Executing a Jupyter Notebook from the Command Line with --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name
I am creating a bash command that will allow me to execute a jupyter notebook from the command line. Regardless of which import library I reference first, I get the error "No Module Named 'example'". Below is the code I have in my .sh file
#!/bin/bash

source /Users/name/Documents/repos/repo_venv/bin/activate

cd /Users/name/Documents/repos/project1/project1.1 #this is the directory my notebook is in

# Run the Jupyter Notebook file
jupyter nbconvert --execute --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=repo_venv --to notebook file1.ipynb

deactivate

I have used the jupyter kernelspec list command to make sure I am referencing the right kernel in the ExecutePreprocessor function. Also, when I run the following in my notebook
import sys 
print(sys.executable)

it returns /Users/name/Documents/repos/repo_venv/bin/python
Finally, I've used pip list in repo_venv to make sure I have the libraries installed and they all are.
Are there any other reasons this doesn't seem to be referencing the right venv?

Is the call to the import example in your notebook? You need to put the example files with the notebook or add it to your path, it would seem.

@Wayne Yes, import example is in my notebook. Regardless of which library I am importing, the first one is referenced in the error. So if I have import pandas first, it'll be referenced in the error. If I comment that out and have import numpy first, it'll be referenced in the error.
Can you clarify the second sentence?

Wherever jupyter nbconvert is running, it isn't accessing your installed packages. (My second sentence is hopefully getting at sorting that out.) I see mention of repo_venv in the script's source line and in the kernel name; however, either that is the wrong environment or it isn't working as you expect. You should be able to run those steps that you presently have in the first two command lines of .sh file on the command line and try troubleshooting them by running which python and python -c "import example" and/or `python -c "import pandas".

Another way to get at this, given what you say about pip list. ... If you put %pip list inside a new notebook and run that the way you are trying to run file1.ipynb with your .sh file, what happens? Does what is listed in the result of %pip list run in side the notebook match what you think?

Idea based on here: convert your jupyter nbconvert command to python -m jupyter nbconvert --execute --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=repo_venv --to notebook file1.ipynb
